# Creating and destroying AVFoundation classes on background queues?

Tags: ios, multithreading, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to eliminate some Main Thread performance hits that occur when I allocate AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem and AVURLAsset on the main thread.  Has anyone had experience with moving allocation/releasing of these objects to a background thread?  Similarly, can an AVPlayer's currentItem be set on a background queue?

Answer (score 3):

The following will definitely hurt scrolling performance

- Creating AVPlayer, 10 fps drop
- Adding player to AVPlayerLayer, 15 fps drop
- Start play, 15/25 fps drop
- Pause play, 15 fps drop
- Deallocate AVPlayer, 20+ fps drop

I tried with allocate AVPlayer from a background thread, however, AVFoundation will switch back to main and perform the allocation/initialization from main. Same with play/pause.

I have some success with deallocating AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem on a background thread. Basically you need to clear out last reference to AVPlayer from your background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if it isn't documented to be thread safe in the classes documentation, you shouldn't use an object of that class across multiple threads.

More to the point, while there's a benefit to doing less on the main thread, allocating `AVPlayer`, `AVPlayerItem` and `AVURLAsset`'s won't ever practically be a bottleneck that you need to worry about. Instead, you should run Instruments and find real performance problems, and focus on those instead.

Comment: I'm finding this is not the case. Allocating an AVPlayer item with a URL tends to slow down scroll performance – even if done on a background thread. Exactly why this happens I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @rob is correct. You take a noticeable hit in scrolling performance when trying to make all of this work. Rob, did you ever make any progress on this issue?

Comment: @user3344977 I found that I could mitigate but not fix scroll performance by putting everything I possibly could on background threads. (AVAsset allocation alone was taking up to 30ms on my iPhone 6.) I also did a test where I used a minimal video that was <1k and loaded on the device, and that made no difference – that is, decreasing video file size and loading from disk did not improve scroll performance. It seems there is an unavoidable ~15ms lock-up of the main thread when starting a movie. I still don't know what it is – time profiling was not much help.

Comment: @rob Thanks. I think there's just only so much optimization you can do... in the end AVPlayer has some flaws. Looks like the only way to achieve 60fps scrolling like this is to roll your own player.